# Python regex: re.findall method throwing list index out of range error

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm learning web scraping using python regular expression and practicing the following script [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56984080/beautiful-soup-doesnt-return-all-tags) but when I run, it's throwing  `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.att.com/buy/phones/'
html_text = requests.get(url).text

data = json.loads(re.findall(r'__NEXT_DATA__ = (.*?});', html_text)[0])
print(json.dumps(data['props']['pageProps']['deviceList'], indent=4))
```

Comment: Your expression isn't being found- __NEXT_DATA.... in html_text is bringing back an empty list.

Comment: Try this instead `soup.select_one("[id='__NEXT_DATA__']").get_text(strip=True)`. There are three `__NEXT_DATA__` on that page and your pattern is having trouble finding the right one.

Comment: `findall` doesn't throw that error. As Cameron said, your expression isn't found so `findall` returns an empty list. How do you expect to get `[0]` from an empty list? It's important to understand what your error traceback means, and how to isolate the problem in a line that contains multiple expressions. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is a direct result of web dynamics. Websites are not static where a solution from 2019 possibly not working. Instead of using custom Regex to find the JSON, I would suggest to use Beautiful Soup (bs4) for more robust script.

The following code will give you want you wanted;

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.att.com/buy/phones/'
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', id='__NEXT_DATA__').text)
print(json.dumps(data['props']['initialReduxState']['solr']['deviceList'], indent=4))
```

> Explanation of the code

The request libraries gets the raw HTML text from the given URL and we used bs4 to parse it. The default is lxml parser. Then, we have use the find function to search for script with the id named '**NEXT_DATA**' where we get the text inside of the script which is a JSON. Finally, we have loaded with json library and located the new position of 'deviceList'. For more documentation of bs4, please see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc

> First output from the long JSON

```
{
        "firstNet": "notApplicable",
        "productFamily": "Phn13",
        "comingSoon": false,
        "skuId": "sku2360531",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "displayContentItems": [],
        "deviceGroup": "network",
        "starRatings": 4.5962,
        "numOfStarReviews": 2959,
        "mobileImageUrl": [
            "/idpassets/global/devices/phones/apple/apple-iphone-13/defaultimage/pink-hero-zoom.png?imwidth=219"
        ],
        "largeImageURL": "//www.att.com/catalog/en/skus/images/apple-iphone%2013-pink-450x350.png",
        "model": "iPhone 13",
        "productName": "Apple iPhone 13",
        "billCode": "6164D",
        "name": "jared",
        "PDPPageURL": [
            "/buy/phones/apple-iphone-13-128gb-pink.html"
        ],
        "prepaid": "",
        "productURL": "//www.att.com/cellphones/iphone/apple-iphone-13.html#sku=sku2360531",
        "condition": "New",
        "productId": "prod10340592",
        "htmlColor": "#FADDD7",
        "isPrepaid": false,
        "isRefurbished": false,
        "isPreOwned": false,
        "isPrePreOrderable": false,
        "type": "Device",
        "color": "Pink",
        "FinalPriceIRU": 22.23,
        "FinalPriceCRU": 22.23,
        "FinalPlanType": "monthly",
        "FinalPrice": 22.23,
        "FinalnextUpCharge": [
            0
        ],
        "FinalIRUnextUpCharge": [
            0
        ],
        "FinalCRUnextUpCharge": [
            0
        ],
        "FinalCommitmentTerm": "NE36MNUP",
        "FinalCommitmentTermCRU": "NE36MNUP",
        "FinalCommitmentTermIRU": "NE36MNUP",
        "FinalBasePriceCRU": 22.23,
        "FinalBasePriceIRU": 22.23,
        "FinalPlanTypeCRU": "monthly",
        "FinalPlanTypeIRU": "monthly",
        "FinalBasePrice": 22.23,
        "FinalTermLength": 36,
        "FinalTermLengthIRU": 36,
        "FinalTermLengthCRU": 36,
        "consumerOfferDescription": "$0 w/Trade",
        "cruOfferDescription": "$0 w/Trade",
        "iruOfferDescription": "$0 w/Trade",
        "consumerOfferDescriptionAL": "$0 w/Trade",
        "consumerOfferDescriptionUP": "$0 w/Trade",
        "iruOfferDescriptionAL": "$0 w/Trade",
        "iruOfferDescriptionUP": "$0 w/Trade",
        "cruOfferDescriptionAL": "$0 w/Trade",
        "cruOfferDescriptionUP": "$0 w/Trade",
        "allProductIds": [
            "prod10340592",
            "prod10340591",
            "prod10340593"
        ],
        "allSkuIds": [
            "sku2360531",
            "sku2360535",
            "sku2360534",
            "sku2360527",
            "sku2360528",
            "sku2360530",
            "sku2360529",
            "sku2360537",
            "sku2360526",
            "sku2360536",
            "sku2360533",
            "sku10940263",
            "sku10940264",
            "sku10940268",
            "sku10940269"
        ],
        "allBillCodes": [
            "6164D",
            "6166D",
            "6162D",
            "6165D",
            "6163D",
            "6169D",
            "6171D",
            "6167D",
            "6170D",
            "6168D",
            "6174D",
            "6176D",
            "6172D",
            "6175D",
            "6173D"
        ],
        "tradeInLegalModalPath": "/idpassets/fragment/legal/prod/legalcontent/wireless/offers/19900012/19900012_offertray_lm.cmsfeed.js",
        "tradeInLegalText": "Req\u2019s elig. unlimited (speed restr\u2019s apply) & trade-in. Price after 36 mo. credits. Other terms apply. ",
        "tradeInShortLegalLinkLabel": "See offer details",
        "tradeInPromoReference": "19900012",
        "tradeInMonthlyPromoPrice": "0",
        "tradeInLegalModalPathCRU": "/idpassets/fragment/legal/prod/legalcontent/wireless/offers/19900012/19900012_offertray_lm.cmsfeed.js",
        "tradeInLegalTextCRU": "Req\u2019s elig. unlimited (speed restr\u2019s apply) & trade-in. Price after 36 mo. credits. Other terms apply. ",
        "tradeInShortLegalLinkLabelCRU": "See offer details",
        "tradeInPromoReferenceCRU": "19900012",
        "tradeInMonthlyPromoPriceCRU": "0"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting  ` raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` from your solution. Please have a look on it

Comment: JSON is part of Python standard library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) so that I would suggest alter the behavior of the code based on your Python version. I have tested the code snippet on Python 3.7.12